# Grails 2.5.3 controller params is read-only on tests but not on run-app

Tags: grails

In a controller action I have a code like this:

```
if (!format)
{
    params.format = 'json'
}
```

This works perfectly on run-app

But testing the same code from an integration test, I get:

```
groovy.lang.ReadOnlyPropertyException: Cannot set readonly property: params for class: com.cabolabs.ehrserver.api.RestController
```

Any ideas of what is wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think a nice explanation can be found here: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Controller-Unit-Test-problem-while-params-as-a-map-td3039994.html

It boils down to the fact that `params` are not an instance a Map but rather an instance of the class `GroovyPageAttributes`.